# Prevent Safari from auto extracting ZIP files (since sometimes it only extracts the first member)

Tags: http, safari, zip, webkit

When serving ZIP files from an HTTP server, Safari seems to auto-unzip ZIP files. How can it be stopped from doing so via changes in the server? Is there a way of constructing ZIP files so it won't, or some HTTP header to set?

I know you can configure Safari to not do this, but looking for a method that doesn't involve the website visitor having to take extra steps before download.

This is related to the issue reported at https://github.com/uktrade/stream-zip/pull/42 where in some cases Safari seems to only auto-extract the first member of certain ZIP files and others members just seem to disappear. Wondering how to make sure it *doesn't* ever try to to that, and thus side-stepping the apparent bug.

Answer (score 1):

The zip files are very likely being served with the MIME type: `application/zip` (or alternatives `application/x-zip-compressed`, `application/zip-compressed`, which tells the client what it is. I'm sure that if you could get rid of that Content-Type, then Safari would not know to extract it. However when I tried to do that on my hosting service, cPanel said "you can not alter the system defined MIME type values"! (The system defines `application/zip` for files that end in .zip.) I can only add new MIME types on that service. Hopefully you have more control over yours.

Comment: So far I'm trying on a local http server with various MIME types. I can get it to show the zip contents inline by passing say `text/plain` (which just looks like gibberish), but as soon it's downloadable - either via `content-type` or via `content-disposition`, it seems to invoke its auto extraction.

Comment: Once again, something I'm sure of turns out to be wrong.